# 0th index skipped when comparing elements between 2 sorted list

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am comparing elements in a sorted list using the following loop (using Eclipse).

```
//Test Code
public static boolean isPermutation(String sIn1, String sIn2){
    Boolean test = false;
    if (sIn1.length() != sIn2.length()) {
        test = false;
        return test;
    } else {
    List<Character> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Character> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sIn1.length(); i++){
        a1.add(sIn1.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sIn2.length(); i++){
        a2.add(sIn2.charAt(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(a1);
    Collections.sort(a2);
    System.out.println(a1);
    System.out.println(a2);
    for (int x = 0; x < a1.size(); x++) {
        if (a1.get(x) == a2.get(x)) {
            System.out.println(x);
            test = true;
        } else {
            test = false;
            if (test = false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    System.out.println(test);
    return test;
}

//Test Case  
Pset1.isPermutation("abcd", "bcdA"));

//Sorted List 
[a, b, c, d]
[A, b, c, d]
```

Running only (1) for a list with 4 elements, the output I get is:

0 
1
2
3

whereas running (2), I get:

1
2
3

x is a local variable for this loop and is not declared anywhere else. I don't understand why x = 0 is skipped when I run this (I want to start comparing from the 0th index element in the list). Could someone please explain?

Thank you!

Edit: Added full code and test case.

Comment: Probably because `a1.get(0) != a2.get(0)`. Hard to tell without `a1` and `a2` source code.

Comment: You're right! But if a1.get(0) != a2.get(0), wouldn't it enter the else loop, and then break away from the whole 'for' loop altogether?

Comment: No, because `if (test = false) {` should be `if (test == false) {` or better `if (!test) {`

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Comment: This is not a forum, so please don't add stuff like "closed" or "answered" into the title. If there is an answer, then accept it (if it helped your), if not, then you could create an answer and explain the solution for your problem.

Comment: Create an answer please, so everyone could enjoy it please

Comment: @Tunaki because `test` is assigned to `false` in the line just above the `if` statement, this check is redundant. The `break` can be moved outside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Input:**

> - [a, b, c, d]
> - [A, b, c, d]

0 wasn't printed, because the characters 'a' and 'A' aren't equal. If you want a caseinsensitiv solution, you should do something like this:

**Case Insensitive:**

```
test = true;
for (int x = 0; x < a1.size(); x++) {
    if (a1.get(x).LOWERCASE_LETTER == a2.get(x).LOWERCASE_LETTER) {
        System.out.println(x);
    } else {
        test = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also the condition in the if statement wasn't alright (*assign Operator instead of equal to*), and it would never break the for-loop.
In my opinion the if statement is unnecessary, because it would never be false.

If you compare two Objects i would suggest to use the equals method or a comparator and maybe generics.

**Example with Comparator:**

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String sIn1, String sIn2, Comparator<Character> comp) {
    /* your code */
    test = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < a1.size(); x++) {
        if (comp.compare(a1.get(x), a2.get(x)) == 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
        } else {
            test = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Test Case  
    Pset1_WithComparator.isPermutation("abcd", "bcdA", new Comparator<Character>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
            return o1.LOWERCASE_LETTER - o2.LOWERCASE_LETTER;
        }
    });
}
```

**Example with Comparator and Generic**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isPermutation(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Comparator<T> comp) {
    Boolean test = false;
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        test = false;
    } else {
        Collections.sort(list1);
        Collections.sort(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);

        test = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < list2.size(); x++) {
            if (comp.compare(list2.get(x), list2.get(x)) == 0) {
                System.out.println(x);
            } else {
                test = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(test);
    return test;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Test Case  
List<Character> l1 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'a','b','c','d'}));
List<Character> l2 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'A','b','c','d'}));
    Pset1_WithComparatorAndGenerics.isPermutation(l1, l2, new Comparator<Character>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
            return o1.LOWERCASE_LETTER - o2.LOWERCASE_LETTER;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < a1.size(); x++) {
        if (a1.get(x) == a2.get(x)) {
            //System.out.println(x);
            test = true;
        } else {
            test = false;
            // changed from test = false
            if (test == false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

System.out.println(x) did not print 0 for x = 0 because it went into the else loop. It did not properly escape ('break') the for-loop because the condition wasn't properly implemented.

Comment: Why would you need a check if you just assigned to `false`?

Comment: I essentially wanted to compare if two strings are permutations of each other and return a boolean False if they are not. That is why I assigned test = false in the else loop. On hindsight, I did not need the check and could have just broken out from the for-loop after assigning test = false.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the loop didn't output **0** is because `A` is not equals to `a`, but in the next loop , you made a wrong way to compare `test` with **boolean** value, you should use `test == false` instead of `test = false`.